# Android send Notification daily even if the app is closed

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I just tried out the AlarmManager to force my app to send a notification every day at 3pm. But this only works if the app is still in background. 
When the user kills the app, the AM doesn't work anymore. What can I do instead of AlarmManager to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6):

> But this only works if the app is still in background.

No, it will work nicely even if the app is not running, such as having its process be terminated by Android to free up memory for other apps.

> When the user kills the app, the AM doesn't work anymore

If by "kills", you mean the user tapped on "Force Stop" for your app in Settings, then your alarms are unscheduled, and nothing of your app will run again until the user runs your app manually (e.g., taps on your launcher activity in the home screen).

I have heard reports that some devices, made by brain-dead manufacturers, do the same thing as "Force Stop" when users stop an app from a device-supplied "task manager". That is unfortunate.

In any other conventional definition of "kills", your alarms are unaffected.

> What can I do instead of AlarmManager to achieve what I want?

Nothing. If the user force-stops your app, the user does not want your app to run, and so your app will not run.

Comment: But lets say we take an example: WhatsApp. When WhatsApp isn't running on my phone, I still get notifications for new messages in WhatsApp. Thats exact what I want to do, how is this possible?

Comment: @Phil: They use `AlarmManager` (directly or indirectly), or they receive push notifications (since they happen to be a messaging app). Either of those will be blocked if the user force-stops WhatsApp, and either of those will work in other cases.

Comment: Mhm I uses AlarmManager too and I have a button on my phone, which shows me after pressing, all started apps and I can simple swipe right or left to close them. If I do this with WhatsApp, Notifications are still sent, If I do this with my app, Notifications aren't sent anymore

Comment: @Phil: Then you need to debug your app. You can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see the scheduled `AlarmManager` events. For example, it may be that `AlarmManager` is working just fine, but you made mistakes in your use of alarm types, such as not using `WakefulIntentService` or `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` with a `_WAKEUP` alarm.

Comment: How do I use WakefulIntentService and WakefulBroadcastReceiver? I'm just using the normal BR and Service

Comment: @Phil: That's not going to work reliably. You can read about `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), and [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast). My `WakefulIntentService` has documentation [on the project site](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), and [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sticky background service to get your notifications sent anytime you want. With a simple running service you can schedule any task. Consider using a wake_lock for long running tasks that may require to keep the processor from sleeping. Also take into consideration the battery consumption.
Regards.